# Redux action no longer works after update from 5 to 7

Tags: react-redux

I update `react-redux` from 5 to 7.1.3.

My actions are not firing any more. Did they do some braking changes?

My component:
...

```
class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
..
this.props.setUser(user);
..
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IRootReducer) => ({
  user: state.globalReducer.user,
});

export default withRouter<any>(connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setUser
})(App));
```

My action:

```
export const setUser = (user: IUser) => dispatch => {
  console.log('fire') // not firing
  dispatch({
    type: SET_USER,
    payload: {
      user
    }
  });
};
```

In the examples they have the `dispatch` in the component. But I don't want to change all my code. Also I dispatch actions from other actions.

How do I solve this without too much change in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Your `setUser` action returns a function which have `dispatch` as an argument. I am assuming you are using the https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk package, otherwise the `setUser` action could not work. Maybe try to update the `redux-thunk` package.

Comment: Problem was I forgot to apply redux-thunk as middleware when I reconfigures the store with react-redux. You pointed in the right direction so I'll accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to dispatch your setUser action:

```
class App extends React.Component<IProps, IState> {
..
this.props.dispatch(this.props.setUser(user));
..
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: IRootReducer) => ({
  user: state.globalReducer.user,
});

export default withRouter<any>(connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setUser
})(App));
```

If you want to use dispatch from your action file you need to change this part:

```
export default withRouter<any>(connect(mapStateToProps, {
  setUser
})(App));
```

to this:

```
export default withRouter<any>(connect(mapStateToProps, (dispatch) => {
  return {
   setUser: (user) => dispatch(setUser(user))
  }
})(App));
```

Comment: I want to use dispatch from my action file. Not my component.

Comment: Still, i want to do dispatch in my action file. Not my component. In old version of react-redux, the dispatch was somehow passed to the action file.